# Software monitoring system sounds output

Tags: audio, windows-11

I wanted to know if there is a software that can monitor the sound output in decibels on Windows. I often use headphones on my PC and I am a bit concerned about my ears. On my Samsung phone (Android 14) there is an option to see data about how loud (in decibels) I am listening to it (Settings -> Digital Wellbeing -> Loud listening time).

[image: A screenshot of my Samsung's volume monitor app with measurements of sound volume from the last 24 hours]

Thank you :D

Comment: I suspect your phone hasn't really a clue how loud you were listening. Anything under 70dBSPL is pretty innocuous. There are a myriad 'dB' lists online of relative volumes of common sounds - https://soundproofingguide.com/decibels-level-comparison-chart/

Answer (score 2):

Given that the actual audio levels depend on the final output equipment and the distance/coupling between it and the sensor or ears there is no way for your computer to monitor the **actual** audio levels without a calibrated sensor or microphone placed where your ears would be. In the case of headphones *and especially in ear headphones* this is especially impractical.

You can purchase such sensors, some with a connection to the computer, but headphones do make these a problem.

Note that the readings in dB are a log scale of the ***output*** levels not the actual audio levels which are measured in dB(A).

*A good rule of thumb is that if it is loud enough that you are worried it is probably too loud!*

It is also important to note that the type of sound and the duration of exposure also have a significant impact on hearing damage as well as actual sound levels.